# unable to start activity from onPostexecute() using interface

Tags: android, interface, android-asynctask

I need to start another activity from the onPosExecute method of the AsyncTask. The AsyncTask is a seperate class and not in any activity class.

I have used an interface to do so. The codes are:

This is the onPostExecute() method

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
    Log.v("JSON", json);
    Log.v("updateUI",""+updateUI);
   updateUI.changeActivity();

}
```

This is the interface

```
public interface UpdateUIListener {

public void changeActivity();
}
```

And this is the part of the activity class where the interface is implemented

```
   @Override
public void changeActivity() {
    Intent blah=new Intent(this,SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(blah);
    finish();
}
```

When I run the code, a null pointer exception shows up, at the line

```
 Intent blah=new Intent(this,SplashActivity.class);
```

My stacktrace is:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at   android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3546)
        at com.autofoyer.SignUpActivity.changeActivity(SignUpActivity.java:79)
        at com.autofoyer.common.MyClientTask.onPostExecute(MyClientTask.java:73)
        at com.autofoyer.common.MyClientTask.onPostExecute(MyClientTask.java:23)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I need to know what is causing and How to solve the null point exception. I need to start and activity from the onPostExecute method. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show full code of your AsyncTask and how it called from Activity/Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably instantiate `updateUI` with `new SplashActivity()` or similar. You can't do that. Instead you have to pass a `Context` into your `AsyncTask` and use that to call `startActivity()` . You probably start the `AsyncTask` from some `Activity`, so just pass that `Activity` as a `Context` when instantiating the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I need to use the asynctask for a number of activites, so I dont want to place it in one activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ci_ . I passed the context to asyncTask and that did the trick.